# Set image From URL as wallpaper - Glide Library -

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I'm trying to create a wallpapers application using **Glide library**, in my app I have 4 categories and each category I have range of images displayed it by their URLs like this picture:

[image]

And when I click on a picture Appears in this format:

[image]

I have problem with **Set as wallpaper** I tried everything but doesn't work for me, this is my **file.java** responsible for fetching a picture and showing it.

```
public class Pop extends Activity {
int width,height;
String url;
LinearLayout llDownloadWallpaper,llsetwallpapers;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop);
    llDownloadWallpaper = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llDownloadWallpaper);
    llsetwallpapers = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llSetWallpaper);
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    this.width = dm.widthPixels;
    this.height = dm.heightPixels;
    getWindow().setLayout((int) (((double) this.width) * 0.9d), (int) (((double) this.height) * 0.75d));
    getIntent().getSerializableExtra("WallpaperURL");
    this.url = (String)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("WallpaperURL");
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(this.url).into((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageSelectTo));
    llDownloadWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // download image
        }
    });
    final ImageView userImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageSelectTo);
    llsetwallpapers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // set as wallpapers
           /* try {
                WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setBitmap(Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).asBitmap().into(width,height).get());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/
          }
        });
     }
  }
```

**XML**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/linealL"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#65000000">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageSelectTo"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
<!-- Set as wallpaper button -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llSetWallpaper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_corner"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/SetAsWallpaper"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Download wallpaper button -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llDownloadWallpaper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_corner"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/Download"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this change in your code.

```
llsetwallpapers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Glide.with(this)
    .load(path)
    .asBitmap()
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super 
                  Bitmap> glideAnimation) {


 WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setBitmap(resource);

        }
    });

    });
 }
```

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaaaaanks so much you save my day

Comment: Sorry For Disturb ,please if you know how  i can add download feature

Comment: Deprecated method

Comment: Can you please help me i am stucking in  Download Image and store it in local directory. Please help me out

Answer (score 2):

Iam not gone give you the exact answer, but i will give you some idea

First on click get the URL of the clicked image, Then Set that Image as a background image Like this.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
        InputStream ins = null;
        try {
            ins = new URL("http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/inspiring-creative-design-mobile-phone-wallpapers.jpg").openStream();
            wpm.setStream(ins);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Also don't forget to add the permission to manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case its working,

```
   wallpaperManager=WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
   
   // Button Onclick

   setWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
                InputStream ins = null;
                try {
                      ins = new URL(url).openStream();
                      wallpaperManager.setStream(ins);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                }
                FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set Successfully", 
                FancyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, FancyToast.SUCCESS, false).show();
            }
         });
```

Please remember to add the setWallpaper and internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

Answer (score 0):

with Glid4+ I did like this:

```
private void setAsWallpaper() {
        Glide.with(requireContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .load(listItem.get(position).getWallpaperImage())
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        try {
                            WallpaperManager.getInstance(requireContext()).setBitmap(resource);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                });
    }
```